# BackboneJS - Subviews navigation

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-routing

I have a pretty simple mainmenu with 4 anchors and the relevant views to them. Anyhow, on one of those views I want to add a little submenu with 3 tabs, which after clicking them they show a different view. I figured out how to do it with `pushState:false` but what I want is a clean URL. Right now, my URL would look like `http://localhost/myproject/#secondpage/subview1` or `http://localhost/myproject/#secondpage/subview2` etc etc. So does anyone know how I do achieve `http://localhost/secondpage` no matter which subview/tab is triggered?

Im using RequireJS and HandlebarsJS (for HTML-templating)

So right now my code (snippets) look like this:

Router.js

```
routes: {
'': 'index',
'firstpage' : 'firstpage',
'secondpage' : 'secondpage',
'secondpage/sub1' : 'sub1',
'secondpage/sub2' : 'sub2',
'secondpage/sub3' : 'sub3',
'thirdpage' : 'thirdpage'
},

Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: false
});
```

My HTML with the anchors:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a class="sub1" href="#secondpage/sub1">Bands</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="sub2" href="#secondpage/sub2">Koncert</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="sub3" href="#secondpage/sub3">Locations</a>
</li>   
</ul>
```

and my View looks like

```
  define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/SubMenu.html'],

    function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {


        'use strict';

        var SubMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

            template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this);
            },

            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template());
                return this;
            }

        });

        return SubMenuView;


    }
  );
```

Another thing is: should I move the actions to the View by setting events? I kind of tried that but it didnt work since the Views are defined in the router...

What I tried is to set `pushState:true`, then I removed the `secondpage/sub1` thingies in my router, then in my View I wrote:

```
events: {
'click a.sub1': 'sub1',
},

sub1: function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var sub1Router = new Backbone.Router();
   var route = '/secondpage/';
   sub1Router.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
},
```

but that didnt work, that gave me **URL not found** so...

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance...

**[UPDATE]** 
OK, so by request, here is my (new) router:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'firstpage' : 'firstpage',
    'secondpage' : 'secondpage',
    'thirdpage' : 'thirdpage'
},

initialize: function () {
    var self = this;

    //Views
    this.mainMenuView = new MainMenuView({el:'#mainMenu'}).render();
    this.subMenuView = new SubMenuView();

    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true
    });

},

index: function () {
    var self = this;
},

firstpage: function() {
    this.firstpageView = new FirstpageView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
},

secondpage: function() {
    this.secondpageView = new SecondpageView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
    this.subMenuView = new SubMenuView({el:'#subMenu'}).render();
},

thirdpage: function() {
    var thirdpageView = new ThirdpageView({ el:'#topContent', collection:this.categoryCollection}).render();
},

sub1: function() {
    this.sub1View = new Sub1View({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
},

sub2: function() {
    this.sub2View = new Sub2View({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
},

sub3: function() {
    this.sub3View = new Sub3View({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
}                       


});

return Router;
}
```

And my (new) View looks like:

```
var SubMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

events: {
'click .sub1': 'sub1',
'click .sub2': 'sub2',
'click .sub3': 'sub3',

},

sub1: function(event) {
    var sub1Router = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = '/secondpage';
    sub1Router.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
},

sub2: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sub2Router = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = '/secondpage';
    sub2Router.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
},

sub3: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sub3Router = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = '/secondpage';
    sub3Router.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
},              

initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
}

 });

 return SubMenuView;
```

And my (new) HTML template:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a class="sub1" href="/secondpage/">Sub1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="sub2" href="/secondpage/">Sub2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="sub3" href="/secondpage/">Sub3</a>
</li>   
</ul>
```

Hope this can contribute to more input/suggestions... This is really driving me nuts which make me consider using .show() and .hide() jquery method even if i dont really want...

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is how backbone routing works, either you use '/secondpage/sub1' and use server routes, or use '#secondpage/sub1' and hit backbone routing.  Either way the address bar is going to update with your URL.

One alternative option is to use a events inside the view, handling a click event and updating the view's template accordingly.

However, if you're intent on using routes then maybe have a look at [clickify.js](https://gist.github.com/maxw/3014727).  I haven't used it myself yet, although I have it bookmarked for potential future use... sounds like it might do what you want.

Comment: hmm maybe I wasnt clear enough. I would rather avoid using some script for such a feature which probably should and can be done in a clear backbone way...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in your router :

```
Backbone.history.navigate('secondpage');
```

after all the work is done (the models are fetched the views are rendered)

Comment: That will still update the url?  Also will not hit the routes unless trigger option set to true e.g. Backbone.history.navigate('secondpage', true);

Comment: I think that's what SHT is asking for.

Comment: Maybe he is, perhaps it's not clear... but his question starts with `which after clicking them they show a different view.` and Backbone.history.navigate without trigger set to true, and pushState: false, will not (on it's own) load the views, just update the url.

Comment: I agree with you, but my proposition as I mentioned (**try to use this in your router**) that's mean after all the work is done (the models is fetched the views are rendered) he has to use it just to update the url.

Comment: I see where you're coming now; should work, albeit a little hacky.